# Java Sort functions

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections

In java the collections.sort used merge sort algorithm instead of quick sort. But Arrays.sort uses quick sort. ( And i am not sure about above fact but i found this on internet like on website such as [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/520171/java/java/Collections-sort-merge-sort-insteadof) if they don't use that algoritjm please tell me)

Now i know average complexity of both algorithm is same. Only fact is quicksort worst is O(n^2) but that's not to common.
And we are not concerned with space in today's world so it doesn't matter that merge sort is not in-place algorithm.
But we concerned with stability so why we use quick sort for array.sort because its not a stable algorithm. Is it because it only concerned about integer's but i don't think that's a good reason.

Comment: I thought they both used TimSort. I need to check the source code.

Comment: Oh u sure i found that on internet.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary "I found that on the internet" is pretty unhelpful.  Where'd you find it?

Comment: @dimo414 there is something here to http://www.coderanch.com/t/520171/java/java/Collections-sort-merge-sort-insteadof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your premise can be easily verified by looking at the relevant [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html), or even the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/).  First, notice that [`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) simply delegates to [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) ([source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l164)):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
}
```

So these two methods will have the same behavior and runtime.  As noted in the documentation, the implementation is [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), a merge sort and insertion sort hybrid.  It is guaranteed to be stable.  So, sorting objects works the same whether you have an array or a collection.

What the article you link to is referring to is sorting *primitive* arrays.  There are fewer assumptions that need to be made about primitive arrays, notably equal primitives are, by definition, indistinguishable.  That means there is no need to ensure a stable sort.  You'll notice the documentation for the primitive sort methods, like [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-), says nothing about the stability of these sorting methods, because such a detail is meaningless.  Stability only matters when sorting data that can be equal but not identical.

Answer (score 8):

`Arrays.sort` uses a dual-pivot quicksort algorithm for primitive arrays only, where there is no difference between stable and unstable sorting algorithms.  This is generally considered to be slightly faster but it isn't stable, so it's only used in cases where stability is irrelevant.

`Arrays.sort` on object arrays, and `Collections.sort`, use Timsort, which is a mergesort variation that does a stable sort.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.sort` does not really use the common quicksort implementation, the javadoc specifies:

> The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort  by Vladimir
>   Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm  offers
>   O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other  quicksorts
>   to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically  faster than
>   traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

Have a look at the sort algorithm located in [`DualPivotQuicksort`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#l107); as you can see in the comments different sort algorithms are used depending on the given array.

As for the `Collections` sort method, it calls `sort` on the received implementation which (in the case I verified) delegates to `Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort will be slightly faster than Collections.sort because Collections.sort internally calls Arrays.sort. 
When dealing with primitives, stability is not relevant as primitives of same value can be rearranged without side effects. And Arrays.sort gives additional performance advantage. Hence, for primitive arrays, Arrays.sort would be preferred.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes actually it's about which algo they use and why?