# Custom sorting -

Tags: java

We have unordered set of values as below ex:

```
Name   cost 
---------    - - - - - 
Bbb      100-500
Ccc       500+more
Aaa       1-100
```

We wanted to display the above values in below format(orderby cost).

```
Name   cost 
---------    - - - - - 
Aaa       1-100
Bbb      100-500
Ccc       500+more
```

Is there any possible way to do custom sorting using Java or any best way to sort.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Sort functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785544/java-sort-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Java has a something called a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which is used to sort things.

In in your comparator you can define which properties are used for sorting. For example, to sort by cost you can use the following example. Depending on the types of your properties you can use [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) or otherwise write your own sorting logic (see the Comparator docs).

```
class MyComparator implements java.util.Comparator<MyObject> {
  @Override
  public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
    return o1.cost.compareTo(o2.cost);
  }
}
List<MyObject> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.sort(new MyComparator());

// Or use a lambda instead
items.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.cost.compareTo(o2.cost));
```